# MySQL упорядочивание выборки

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня имеется таблица, содержащая поля A, B, C, D. Допустим, я делаю выборку по данным из полей A и B. Разрешается ли при данных полях выборки делать упорядочивание по полю C?
Например:

```
select A, B
from table
where .....
order by C
```

Разрешается ли упорядочивание по полю, не участвующему в выборке?

Comment: Да. Если нет группировки. При группировке может вызывать ошибку, если к этому полю применяются групповые операции и режим сервера STRICT

Comment: *Разрешается ли упорядочивание по полю, не участвующему в выборке?* Сортировка допустима по любому выражению, допустимому в списке вывода (в первом приближении, исключения Вам пока ни к чему). Можно добавить поле С в выходной набор? да. Значит, и сортировать по нему можно. PS. Вот чес-слово, попробовать было быстрее, чем спрашивать и ждать ответа...